# Unable to run pd.read_excel for scripts that previously worked

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

I am unable to get my python scripts working. To clarify they did work before but now they not, the code itself is not the issue. Whenever I try to run one I get an error specifically on the line `pd.read_excel(file)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automated_cleaning.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(roster_file)
  File "C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 310, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 20, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
  File "C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 90, in import_optional_dependency
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

After searching it seems like the file is corrupt and that is the reason why it is not working. I have tried changing the function to use a different engine but I still get a similar error.

I have tried running pip install to try and fix the package in both Pycharm Terminal and the cmd line but in either scenario it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problem in past, I just updated my xlrd module.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

and also try to put `r` in file path

```
pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\")
```

*I hope you're using python-3.x*

Comment: Where should I run this? I've had no luck running it through the cmd line, I get either a syntax error or pip not a known command.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late but form me the upgrade command didn't work, however uninstalling and installing it again did

pip uninstall xlrd

pip install xlrd